# Will cat poo affect my flowers?

Tags: flowers, compost

We have two cats at home, one of them uses the indoor litter tray while the other prefers to use the flower bed (then diligently spreading soil to cover up the deed).

Should I be concerned? The flower bed in question is seeded with lilies and sunflowers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll guess that the original poster here is not eating the flowers in this bed, but in case that changes I'm offering some extra advice.

Animal feces generally contain pathogens and disease agents that present a risk to humans. It is a risk to 1) put cat feces directly into a garden with fruits, vegetables or anything you plan to eat 2) where you will work the soil with your hands. You can mitigate those risks in a few ways.

- by cleaning the food extremely well before eating.
- by not growing food in that garden bed or keeping the cat out of the area that grows food.
- by wearing gloves and/or washing your hands after working the garden.
- by composting the feces in an appropriate process for an appropriate amount of time before incorporating it into the garden. **Note:** Most at-home compost systems are not rigorously managed to be able to safely process feces from animals that eat meat (e.g. cats and dogs).

I wouldn't be too worried about your cat pooping in a bed of decorative flowers, especially if you don't work the soil in that bed by hand very often.

Answer (score 1):

No, the cat poo will not affect your plants.  Maybe you if you dig it up?  There is something that I picked up on that you should know about.  Lilies of all kinds are poisonous, toxic to cats.  Worse, these plants actually attract cats.  Very poisonous. Some cats might not be attracted right away sometimes never.  I keep my ditties inside because cats out of doors become everyone's cats.  Cats make this very regimented ROUTE in the neighborhood.  Sort of a rectangular regular path they take everyday.  There is no way you can keep cats away from lilies, mouse traps, mole traps, pesticide for mice and rats and in more rural areas, cougar, bobcat, badgers, raccoons...coyotes and dogs.

My cats were always out of door cats, too, until I learned about lilies being toxic to cats, I had my goats eaten by cougars, chickens eaten by raccoons...dog/badger to the death fights...ugh.  Cats dragged away by coyotes and once an owl.

Day lilies, Canna Lilies, Siberian Iris...Calla Lilies might be the only one that is different with the lily name.  Different genus and species all but still plants with the lily in their name are toxic to cats...I wish I hadn't found this site that lists all the toxic plants for cats.

[list of plants toxic to cats](https://www.aspca.org/pet-care/animal-poison-control/cats-plant-list)